# How can I have list of all users logged in my web application

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I use `spring-mvc` and each use who logged in my web app i create a session variable `user` which is a object containing his **id**, name and some others info.

```
session.setAttribute("user", user);
```

What I want is to have a list of all users who are logged in my program.

i want this list to check simultaneous log in because is must be just one access by account.

ps : don't tell me to use `spring-security` because i want to work just with `MVC Interceptor` and `preHandle()`

Answer (score 0):

1) use below code to auto-wire ServletContext object in spring MVC

```
@Autowired
ServletContext context;
```

2) You need to collect all logged in users Set in the context.

```
...
    public void login(User user) {
        logins.add(user);
    }
...    
    public void logout(User user) {
        logins.remove(user);
    }
```

If you're storing the logged-in users in the session already

```
public void sessionDestroyed(HttpSessionEvent event) {
    User user = (User) event.getSession().getAttribute("user");
    if (user != null) {
        Set<User> logins = (Set<User>) event.getSession().getServletContext().getAttribute("logins");
        logins.remove(user);
    }
}
```

Comment: forgot the creation of the logins attribute, but that's trivial.

Comment: Thanks, but you get the idea all i am trying to copy is application context -> session > users :)

Comment: @amitmah you didn't use `ServletContext context` ? can you explain it with more detail

Comment: @amitmah and also what'is the difference between `HttpSessionEvent` and  `HttpSession` ?

Comment: This are old Servlet related objects context, session and events and listeners. ServletContext or context object is a single object used by entire application. Session object created per user session and request objects (HttpServletRequest..) are within Session. Servlet supports various event listeners. For example session lister can track session related events.

Comment: These are internal web app structures and not used widely with MVC app. Since you already store user details in session thats why i suggested this solution. But the ideal solution is not to use any info from Session/Request within MVC.

Comment: and if a user leave without logout (close browser) how can i detect it to remove it from context logins List ?

Comment: This is a classic issue, you can not without session timeouts. What about user minimizes the browser is he active user?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the implementation of HttpSessionListener and ServletContextListener.
HttpSessionListener gets invoked whenever a Session is created or destroyed ,Where as ServletContextListener is invoked when Context is created or destroyed.

**EDIT:** 
The HttpSessionBindingListener can be used on the class whose instances may be stored in the session, such as in your case User.

When an instance of this User get set as a session attribute by HttpSession.setAttribute(), then the valueBound() will be invoked. When it get removed by either HttpSession.removeAttribute(), or an invalidate of the session, or get replaced by another HttpSession.setAttribute(), then the valueUnbound() will be invoked.

Example :

```
public class User implements HttpSessionBindingListener {

@Override
public void valueBound(HttpSessionBindingEvent event) {
    addLoginUser(event);
}

@Override
public void valueUnbound(HttpSessionBindingEvent event) {
    removeLoginUser(event);
}

private void removeLoginUser(HttpSessionBindingEvent event){
if (user != null) {
            ServletContext context = event.getSession().getServletContext();
            Set<User> logins = context.getAttribute("loginUsers");
            logins.remove(this);
    }
 }
   private void addLoginUser(HttpSessionBindingEvent event){

   if (user != null) {
      ServletContext context = event.getSession().getServletContext();
      Set<User> logins = context.getAttribute("loginUsers");
      logins.add(this);
   }
}
```

}

```
 //Use this listner for adding loginUsers when ServletContext is initialized.
 public class MyServletContextListener implements ServletContextListener{
   public void contextInitialized(ServletContextEvent event){
       Set<User> logins = new HashSet<User>();

       //add Initial login to ServletContext
       event.getServletContext().setAttribute("loginUsers", logins);
   }

 public void contextDestroyed(ServletContextEvent event){}

 }
```

Add the following configuration in your web.xml file.

```
<listener>
    <listener-class>
        package.name.MySessionAttributeListener
    </listener-class>
</listener>

 <listener>
    <listener-class>
        package.name.MyServletContextListener
    </listener-class>
</listener>
```

Hope this helps,Thanks.

Comment: but the user is created after the creation of the session !! in your case he will never be added to the collection

Comment: A better approach will be your case you can attach HttpSessionBindingListener